# Spring Boot+Spring MVC+Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

При запуске проекта никаких ошибок не вылетает, все четко
но когда захожу на localhost:8080/get вылетает следующее:
[image: окно браузера при запуске]

уже не знаю как быть и куда копать!
Репозиторий: https://github.com/butr1m/spring_boot.git
Код для генерации БД в корне проекта

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но может нужно написать контроллер который будет обрабатывать запрос с этой ссылкой и в следствии чего будет открывать нужный .jsp с именем. В примере "indexGet".

```
@GetMapping("/get")
    public String get( Model model) {
         //некоторая логика
        model.addAttribute("title", "title");
        return "/indexGet";
    }
```